# formatação de acordo com o conteúdo da célula

Tags: microsoft-excel

tenho uma planilha com as colunas A, B, C e D, onde a coluna A, B e C é um PROCV onde busca o endereço de email em outras planilhas de cada vendedor e a coluna D é o nome do responsável, A, B e C representam cada vendedor da minha equipe, então quando o procv encontra o endereço de email na planilha de cada vendedor ele retorna o tal endereço, quando não ele retorna o texto de não alocado.

minha necessidade, quando o endereço foi encontrado na coluna A pelo procv na coluna responsável que é a D ele exibir vendedor1, quando for encontrado na coluna B, exibir na coluna D vendedor2 e assim por diante.

podem auxiliar?

Comment: Sugiro sempre colocar as tabelas como imagens ou dados para ficar mais claro sua pergunta e poder obter o melhor da comunidade. Fiquei com dúvida sobre sua questão: A coluna D não possui o nome do responsável? E vc quer que fique com o texto "vendedor1" caso a coluna A retorne verdadeira? Quer substituir os dados na coluna D? Poderia deixar mais claro seu questionamento?

Comment: isso exatamente, caso o procv retorne verdadeiro a correspondência fique com o texto vendedor1, que seria o nome do vendedor, lembrando que é uma matriz de 3 colunas e vai aumentando o número de células

Comment: Pode ocorrer de ter três nomes diferentes para cada coluna (A, B e C)? Ou sempre será somente 1 deles preenchidos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se consegui entender e tente a seguinte fórmula na coluna 'D' (célula D1):

```
=SE(E(A1<>"";ÉERROS(PROCURAR("não";A1)));A1;SE(E(B1<>"";ÉERROS(PROCURAR("não";B1)));B1;SE(E(C1<>"";ÉERROS(PROCURAR("não";C1)));C1;"Não alocado")))
```

> Se funcionar na célula `D1` replique para as outras células.